# Change Favicon on Login Screen?

Tags: login, favicon

I have a rather basic question.

Does anyone know how to change the favicon on the login screen?
I have it on all other areas of my site.

But I cannot change it from showing on this page:
http://kindly-remind.com/wp-login.php

It even shows a bluehost favicon and my site has been moved from bluehost.

Answer (score 4):

There is an action for that:

```
add_action( 'login_head', 'wpse_41844_favicon' );

function wpse_41844_favicon()
{
?>
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='/favicon.ico'>
<?php
}
```